# null values in json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a new json string that I am trying to parse and process.
Here is the json:

```
0:"area_type" -> "postal_code"
1:"_id" -> "ps:fl_33991"
2:"_score" -> 21.129333
3:"postal_code" -> "33991"
4:"state_code" -> "FL"
  key:"state_code"
  value:"FL"
5"city" -> "Cape Coral"
6:"country" -> "USA"
  key:"country"
  value:"USA"
7:"centroid" -> Map (2 items)
8:"slug_id" -> "33991"
9:"geo_id" -> "1b329268-fbd0-52ba-9c95-67397b0a7d82"
```

I am getting an error when I am trying to process the state_code: string.

Here is the error message:

**Unhandled exception:
Null check operator used on a null value
#0      Autocomplete.Eval ()
#1      new Autocomplete.fromJson (package:for_testing/models/realtor_property_info_model.dart:85:20)
#2      new GetDataFromApiFromJsonRealtor.fromJson. (package:for_testing/models/realtor_property_info_model.dart:28:58)
#3      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:415:31)**

Here is all the code used to parse the json:

```
getDataFromApiFromJsonRealtorFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

GetDataFromApiFromJsonRealtor getDataFromApiFromJsonRealtorFromJson(
        String str) =>
    GetDataFromApiFromJsonRealtor.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String getDataFromApiFromJsonRealtorToJson(
        GetDataFromApiFromJsonRealtor data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class GetDataFromApiFromJsonRealtor {
  Meta meta;
  List<Autocomplete> autocomplete;

  GetDataFromApiFromJsonRealtor({
    required this.meta,
    required this.autocomplete,
  });

  factory GetDataFromApiFromJsonRealtor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      GetDataFromApiFromJsonRealtor(
        meta: Meta.fromJson(json["meta"]),
        autocomplete: List<Autocomplete>.from(
            json["autocomplete"].map((x) => Autocomplete.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "meta": meta.toJson(),
        "autocomplete": List<dynamic>.from(autocomplete.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Autocomplete {
  String areaType;
  String id;
  double score;
  String? state;
  StateCode stateCode;
  Country country;
  Centroid centroid;
  String slugId;
  String? geoId;
  String? city;
  List<County>? counties;
  bool? countyNeededForUniq;
  String? schoolId;
  String? school;
  String? line;
  String? postalCode;
  bool? hasCatchment;
  String? citySlugId;
  String? county;

  Autocomplete({
    required this.areaType,
    required this.id,
    required this.score,
    this.state,
    required this.stateCode,
    required this.country,
    required this.centroid,
    required this.slugId,
    this.geoId,
    this.city,
    this.counties,
    this.countyNeededForUniq,
    this.schoolId,
    this.school,
    this.line,
    this.postalCode,
    this.hasCatchment,
    this.citySlugId,
    this.county,
  });

  factory Autocomplete.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Autocomplete(
        areaType: json["area_type"],
        id: json["_id"],
        score: json["_score"]?.toDouble(),
        state: json["state"],
        stateCode: stateCodeValues.map[json["state_code"]]!,
        country: countryValues.map[json["country"]]!,
        centroid: Centroid.fromJson(json["centroid"]),
        slugId: json["slug_id"],
        geoId: json["geo_id"],
        city: json["city"],
        counties: json["counties"] == null
            ? []
            : List<County>.from(
                json["counties"]!.map((x) => County.fromJson(x))),
        countyNeededForUniq: json["county_needed_for_uniq"],
        schoolId: json["school_id"],
        school: json["school"],
        line: json["line"],
        postalCode: json["postal_code"],
        hasCatchment: json["has_catchment"],
        citySlugId: json["city_slug_id"],
        county: json["county"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "area_type": areaType,
        "_id": id,
        "_score": score,
        "state": state,
        "state_code": stateCodeValues.reverse[stateCode],
        "country": countryValues.reverse[country],
        "centroid": centroid.toJson(),
        "slug_id": slugId,
        "geo_id": geoId,
        "city": city,
        "counties": counties == null
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(counties!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "county_needed_for_uniq": countyNeededForUniq,
        "school_id": schoolId,
        "school": school,
        "line": line,
        "postal_code": postalCode,
        "has_catchment": hasCatchment,
        "city_slug_id": citySlugId,
        "county": county,
      };
}

class Centroid {
  double lon;
  double lat;

  Centroid({
    required this.lon,
    required this.lat,
  });

  factory Centroid.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Centroid(
        lon: json["lon"]?.toDouble(),
        lat: json["lat"]?.toDouble(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "lon": lon,
        "lat": lat,
      };
}

class County {
  String name;
  String fips;
  StateCode stateCode;

  County({
    required this.name,
    required this.fips,
    required this.stateCode,
  });

  factory County.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => County(
        name: json["name"],
        fips: json["fips"],
        stateCode: stateCodeValues.map[json["state_code"]]!,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "fips": fips,
        "state_code": stateCodeValues.reverse[stateCode],
      };
}

enum StateCode { MN, NY }

final stateCodeValues = EnumValues({"MN": StateCode.MN, "NY": StateCode.NY});

enum Country { USA }

final countryValues = EnumValues({"USA": Country.USA});

class Meta {
  String version;
  int esTook;

  Meta({
    required this.version,
    required this.esTook,
  });

  factory Meta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Meta(
        version: json["version"],
        esTook: json["es_took"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "version": version,
        "es_took": esTook,
      };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Here is the method where I am getting the error:

```
factory Autocomplete.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Autocomplete(
        areaType: json["area_type"],
        id: json["_id"],
        score: json["_score"]?.toDouble(),
        state: json["state"],
        stateCode: stateCodeValues.map[json["state_code"]]!, <<<<  ERROR HERE  >>>>
        country: countryValues.map[json["country"]]!,
        centroid: Centroid.fromJson(json["centroid"]),
        slugId: json["slug_id"],
        geoId: json["geo_id"],
        city: json["city"],
        counties: json["counties"] == null
            ? []
            : List<County>.from(
                json["counties"]!.map((x) => County.fromJson(x))),
        countyNeededForUniq: json["county_needed_for_uniq"],
        schoolId: json["school_id"],
        school: json["school"],
        line: json["line"],
        postalCode: json["postal_code"],
        hasCatchment: json["has_catchment"],
        citySlugId: json["city_slug_id"],
        county: json["county"],
      );
```

How do I handle this line of code?

```
stateCode: stateCodeValues.map[json["state_code"]]!,
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you double-check that the mapping in the 'stateCodeValues' 'enum' is correctly matching the values in your JSON data?

Comment: `stateCodeValues` contains only MN and NY, but json `state_code` is FL

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am learning to code and I didn't even see the statecodevalue.